# Elasticsearch sort by field in top hits parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to sort data by top_hits parameter in search query Elasticsearch but somehow it didn't affect anything. can anyone please help me with this one?

so I've tried using sort as some people said like this :

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "from" : 0,
    "aggs": {
        "by_filter": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "published_at": {
                                "gte": "2019-08-01 00:00:00",
                                "lte": "2023-10-30 23:59:59"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "status": "published"
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "by_created": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "created_by.id",
                        "size": 10
                    },
                    "aggs" : {
                        "count_data": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "created_by.id"
                            }
                        },
                        "hits": {
                            "top_hits": {
                                "sort": [                         <---- the sort query that I found
                                    {
                                        "created_by.name.keyword": {
                                            "order": "desc"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "_source":["created_by.name"],
                                "size": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the result didn't change :

```
"aggregations": {
    "by_filter": {
        "doc_count": 21,
        "by_created": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 3,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 34,
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 3,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "re_article",
                                    "_id": "53822",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "created_by": {
                                            "name": "Edwin"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "sort": [                <--- I think this is the result of the sort
                                        "Edwin"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "count_data": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": 34,
                                "doc_count": 3
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 52,
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 3,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "re_article",
                                    "_id": "338610",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "created_by": {
                                            "name": "Tito"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        "Tito"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "count_data": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": 52,
                                "doc_count": 3
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

what I expected is the buckets show data with created_by name "Tito" first then "Edwin" if that's possible, like this :

```
"aggregations": {
    "by_filter": {
        "doc_count": 21,
        "by_created": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 3,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 52,
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 3,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "re_article",
                                    "_id": "338610",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "created_by": {
                                            "name": "Tito"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "count_data": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": 52,
                                "doc_count": 3
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 34,
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 3,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "re_article",
                                    "_id": "53822",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "created_by": {
                                            "name": "Edwin"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "count_data": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": 34,
                                "doc_count": 3
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I think I pick a wrong example since there's new "sort" field in top_hits result but not really what I'm looking for, can anyone please help? thank you

here's the example of data that I have :

```
{
    "id": 53822,
    "created_at": "2019-09-03 18:17:13",
    "published_at": "2019-09-04 01:17:13",
    "status": "published",
    "created_by": {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "Edwin",
        "role_id": 4,
        "is_active": "Y"
},
{
    "id": 338610,
    "created_at": "2022-10-16 20:48:39",
    "published_at": "2022-10-16 21:08:12",
    "status": "published",
    "created_by": {
        "id": 52,
        "name": "Tito",
        "role_id": 4,
        "is_active": "Y"
},
{
    "id": 54272,
    "created_at": "2019-09-10 08:28:57",
    "published_at": "2019-09-10 15:30:03",
    "status": "published",
    "created_by": {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "Edwin",
        "role_id": 4,
        "is_active": "Y"
}
```

I try to group by field created_by.**id** with count_data aggs and then sort the result by the created_by.**name**, that's why I include the top hits parameter since I need to show the name of the person, not only the id

Also, I need the key of grouping by created_by.id, not by created_by.name eventhough the same id always have the same name

Comment: I am a bit confused about your question now. Could you add a mapping for the field involved and maybe a couple of examples of the records?

Comment: In particular I wonder if `created_by.name` can have different values from the same `created_by.id`. Like can you rename someone but keep the same id and which name do you want to use in this case? I also don't understand the purpose of the count_data aggregation. Can you have the same document created by different people? If this is the case is created_by nested?

Comment: hi there @imotov, I have updated the question hoping it makes everything clear. also, the same id cannot have different name, so the id and the name always have the same value even in the different document

Comment: Could you explain the reason for this requirement: "Also, I need the key of grouping by created_by.id, not by created_by.name eventhough the same id always have the same name". What if this information is made available but not as a key? What is the reason for sorting? Are you planning to page through the results or you expect every request to bring back all result?

Comment: I use created_by.id as a key to combine buckets of data with another query from another index (it already worked). the sorting is because I want to make a report and in those report is showing list of the name, not the id. that's why I need the sorting so it makes easier for user to see the report. if it's possible.. the report is basically showing how many data each person made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no good way of doing this. There are ways to sort aggregations by a numeric values of sub-aggregations, but in your case you need to sort by a string value. There are a few possible workarounds that I am going to list in the order of my preference from the worst to the best:

- Using runtime fields you can combine your key as `Edwin:34` and  use this `Tito:52` and run `terms` aggregation on this runtime field. The problem here is that you will need to parse the key in your application and if you ever change the name without id it will produce two buckets instead of one.
- Since you are already doing post-processing, you can use run terms aggregation by name and use top_hits to retrieve id and use this id for lookup. The problem with this solution is it will break if you have matching names for different ids or if names change.
- Since you are already doing post-processing in your app, you can retrieve name the way you do in your example and just sort buckets in your app.

I know that this is not the solution you were looking for, but to the best of my knowledge that's the best we can do giving the current limitations of the aggregation framework.

Comment: I decided to sort the array on my source code, not by ES query since I think it's easier, in my case. I don't really want to use "name" as a key as it's risky. However, thank you for the insight, I appreciate it a lot!